# Ambari Agent Distro/Conf Select Versions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight, ambari

when I tried to point python 2.7 to python 3.5 on my azure hdinsight cluster. since then It throwing this error. please help
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the alert with this message "Ambari Agent Distro/Conf Select Versions" then please check your "/usr/hdp" directory contents in working and non working hosts.

**Important Note:** You are not supposed to have any extra file or directory inside this directory created by your own apart from the one that comes with HDP installation.

In general this host-level alert is triggered if the distro selector such as hdp-select cannot calculate versions available on this host. This may indicate that /usr/$stack/ directory has links/dirs that do not belong inside of it.

For some versions of ambari this was reported as an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-20648

Hope this helps.